# DataMember attribute set to field or property?

Tags: c#, attributes

In which way should I use DataMemeber attribute ?

I.

```
 [DataMember]
 internal protected string _FirstName="";

[DataMember]
public string FirstName { get { return _FirstName; } 
internal protected set { _FirstName=(value!=null?value:""); } }
```

II.

```
internal protected string _FirstName="";

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get { return _FirstName; } 
    internal protected set { _FirstName=(value!=null?value:""); } }
```

III.

```
[DataMember]
internal protected string _FirstName="";


    public string FirstName { get { return _FirstName; } 
    internal protected set { _FirstName=(value!=null?value:""); } }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1st is definitely not correct, as serialization will happen twice.
Between 2nd and 3rd I personally prefer 2nd, as encapsulating implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The second one. This exposes only the property as a data member. That's what you want. You don't want to have the field exposed.